# Emulation of SE's text input control for tags

Tags: functional-programming, event-handling, react.js, typescript

### Introduction

I used React to write a component, which is meant to be a faithful emulation of the input for "Tags" which you see at the top of every question/topic on SE.

**Why this project?**

If you're wondering why I did that, it was because (apart from a chance it might eventually become useful as a live product), it's an example of a data-driven or user-defined content -- not just static HTML pages -- for which e.g. React might be a useful and relatively modern development tool.

I wanted to learn React, and to verify that I had learned it. This seemed a suitable project:

- Big enough to be interesting
- Small enough to be feasible
- The UI design is well-specified (i.e. evident or documented, can be inspected in every detail), so I could concentrate on implementing the UI and not on designing it.

So far as I know there have been [at least a  couple of dozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37953/139866) SE clones written over the years -- none of which I've looked at, and for all I know none using React.

**Why this component?**

I chose this component for review, as opposed to other source files in the project, for two reasons:

- I found this the most difficult to implement -- it surprised me how much code it needed -- and I don't see an obvious way to refactor it to improve its readability or maintainability
- I know I took some liberties in the other components -- e.g. writing some perhaps-overly-clever hooks, and several functions that aren't "function components" -- if I were reviewing those I suppose I'd find them easy to comment on. But *this* component is as orthodox as I could make it.

**What?**

"It's an emulation of the tag editor" defines the the functional spec -- or see also the "Appearance and behaviour" section at the top of the component's README included below.

The UI output looks e.g. like this when styled:

[image]

If you'd like to try/exercise it, it's running here : https://react-forum2.herokuapp.com/discussions/new

### EditorTags.tsx

Here is the source code for review.

I find it hard to read here, with scrollbars -- you may prefer to [read it on GitHub](https://github.com/cwellsx/react-forum/blob/f058509921d04ac93d12cb589e8d6ae221ed8fc8/src/react/EditorTags.tsx).

```
import React from 'react';
import './EditorTags.css';
// this is to display a little 'x' SVG -- a Close icon which is displayed on each tag -- clicking it will delete the tag
// also to display a little '(!)' SVG -- an Error icon which is displayed in the element, if there's a validation error
import * as Icon from "../icons";
// this simply displays red text if non-empty text is passed to its errorMessage property
import { ErrorMessage } from './ErrorMessage';

// these are the properties of an existing tag, used or displayed by the TagDictionary
interface TagCount {
  key: string,
  summary?: string,
  count: number
}

// these are properties to configurare the validation of tags
interface Validation {
  // whether a minimum number of tags must be defined, e.g. 1
  minimum: boolean,
  // whether a maximum number of tags must be defined, e.g. 5
  maximum: boolean,
  // whether the user can create new tags, or whether tags must match what's already in the dictionary
  canNewTag: boolean,
  // whether the show validation error messages -- they're hidden until the user first presses the form's submit button
  showValidationError: boolean,
  // the href used for the link to "popular tags" in the validation error message -- i.e. "/tags"
  hrefAllTags: string
}

// the results are pushed back to the parent via this callback
export interface OutputTags { tags: string[], isValid: boolean };
type ParentCallback = (outputTags: OutputTags) => void;

// this defines the properties which you pass to the EditorTags functional component
interface EditorTagsProps extends Validation {
  // the input/original tags to be edited (or an empty array if there are none)
  inputTags: string[],
  // the results are pushed back to the parent via this callback
  result: ParentCallback,
  // a function to fetch all existing tags from the server (for tag dictionary lookup)
  getAllTags: () => Promise<TagCount[]>
};

/*
  This source file is long and has the following sections -- see also [EditorTags](./EDITORTAGS.md)

  # Defined outside the React function component:

  - All the type definitions
    - Assert
    - ParentCallback
    - Context
    - State
    - RenderedElement
    - RenderedState
    - InputElement
    - InputState
    - MutableState
    - TagDictionary

  - The reducer
    - action types
    - reducer

  - Various helper functions
    - stringSplice
    - log and logRenderedState
    - getInputIndex
    - getElementStart and getWordStart
    - assertElements and assertWords
    - getTextWidth
    - handleFocus

  - Functions which construct the RenderedState
    - renderState
    - initialState

  # Defined inside the React function component:

  - React hooks
    - errorMessage
    - assert (a function which uses errorMessage and is required by initialState)
    - state 

  - inputRef (data which is used by some of the event handlers)

  - Event handlers (which dispatch to the reducer)
    - getContext
    - handleEditorClick
    - handleDeleteTag
    - handleTagClick
    - handleChange
    - handleKeyDown
    - handleHintResult

  - Tag is a FunctionComponent to render each tag

  - The return statement which yields the JSX.Element from this function component

  # Other function components to display the drop-down hints

  - ShowHints
  - ShowHint
*/

// you could temporarily change this to enable logging, for debugging
const isLogging = false;

/*
  All the type definitions
*/

type Assert = (assertion: boolean, message: string, extra?: () => object) => void;

// this is extra data which event handlers pass (as part of the action) from the function component to the reducer
interface Context {
  inputElement: InputElement;
  assert: Assert;
  result: ParentCallback;
  tagDictionary?: TagDictionary;
  validation: Validation;
};

// this is like the input data from which the RenderedState is calculated
// these and other state elements are readonly so that event handlers must mutate MutableState instead
interface State {
  // the selection range within the buffer
  // this may even span multiple words, in which case all the selected words are in the <input> element
  readonly selection: { readonly start: number, readonly end: number },
  // the words (i.e. the tags when this is split on whitespace)
  readonly buffer: string
};

// this interface identifies the array of <input> and <Tag> elements to be rendered, and the word associated with each
interface RenderedElement {
  // the string value of this word
  readonly word: string;
  // whether this word is rendered by a Tag element or by the one input element
  readonly type: "tag" | "input";
  // whether this word matches an existing tag in the dictionary
  readonly isValid: boolean;
};

// this interface combines the two states, and is what's stored using useReducer
interface RenderedState {
  // the buffer which contains the tag-words, and the selection within the buffer
  readonly state: State;
  // how that's rendered i.e. the <input> element plus <Tag> elements
  readonly elements: ReadonlyArray<RenderedElement>;
  // the current ("semi-controlled") value of the <input> element
  readonly inputValue: string;
  // the hints associated with the inputValue, taken from the TagDictionary
  hints: TagCount[];
  // the validation error message (zero length if there isn't one)
  validationError: string;
}

// this wraps the current state of the <input> control
class InputElement {
  readonly selectionStart: number;
  readonly selectionEnd: number;
  readonly isDirectionBackward: boolean;
  readonly value: string;
  readonly isLeftTrimmed: boolean;
  private readonly inputElement: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(inputElement: HTMLInputElement, assert: Assert, stateValue?: string) {

    let { selectionStart, selectionEnd, selectionDirection, value } = inputElement;
    log("getInput", { selectionStart, selectionEnd, selectionDirection, value });

    assert(!stateValue || stateValue === value, "stateValue !== value");

    // TypeScript declaration says these may be null, though I haven't seen that in practice?
    if (selectionStart === null) {
      assert(false, "unexpected null selectionStart");
      selectionStart = 0;
    }
    if (selectionEnd === null) {
      assert(false, "unexpected null selectionEnd");
      selectionEnd = 0;
    }
    if (selectionStart > selectionEnd) {
      assert(false, "unexpected selectionStart > selectionEnd");
      selectionStart = 0;
    }
    // left trim if the user entered leading spaces
    let isLeftTrimmed = false;
    while (value.length && value[0] === " ") {
      value = value.substring(1);
      --selectionStart;
      --selectionEnd;
      isLeftTrimmed = true;
    }

    this.selectionStart = selectionStart;
    this.selectionEnd = selectionEnd;
    this.isDirectionBackward = selectionDirection === "backward";
    this.value = value;
    this.isLeftTrimmed = isLeftTrimmed;
    this.inputElement = inputElement;
  }

  focus(): void {
    this.inputElement.focus();
  }

  setContent(value: string, start: number, end: number): void {
    // set the value before the selection, otherwise the selection might be invalid
    this.inputElement.value = value;
    this.inputElement.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    // dynammically readjust the width of the input element to match its content
    const width = getTextWidth(value + "0");
    this.inputElement.style.width = `${width}px`;
  }

  toJSON(): string {
    // JSON.stringify cannot handle `inputElement: HTMLInputElement` so the purpose of this is to exclude that
    const printable: string[] = [
      `start: ${this.selectionEnd}`,
      `end: ${this.selectionEnd}`,
      `backward: ${this.isDirectionBackward}`,
      `value: ${this.value}`
    ];
    return printable.join(", ");
  }
}

// this combines the state of the <input> control with the position of the <input> within the RenderedState
// it exists only to help the KeyDown event handlers determine whether keys like ArrowLeft will change the selected word
// beware that, when this runs, the <input> control's value may not yet have been written to the elements[editing].word
class InputState {
  readonly canMoveLeft: boolean;
  readonly canMoveRight: boolean;
  readonly currentStart: number;
  readonly currentEnd: number;
  get nextLeft(): number { return this.currentStart - 1; }
  get nextRight(): number { return this.currentEnd + 1; }

  constructor(state: RenderedState, inputElement: InputElement, assert: Assert) {
    const { elements } = state;
    const { inputIndex, isFirst, isLast } = getInputIndex(elements, assert);
    const elementStart = getElementStart(elements, inputIndex, assert);

    const { selectionStart, selectionEnd, isDirectionBackward, value } = inputElement;

    // if a range is selected then which end of the range is moving?
    const isLeftMoving = (selectionStart === selectionEnd) || isDirectionBackward;
    const isRightMoving = (selectionStart === selectionEnd) || !isDirectionBackward;

    // can move left if at the start of the <input> and if there are other <Tag> elements before the <input> element
    this.canMoveLeft = selectionStart === 0 && !isFirst && isLeftMoving;
    // can move right if at the end of the <input> and if there are other <Tag> elements after the <input> element
    this.canMoveRight = selectionEnd === value.length && !isLast && isRightMoving;

    this.currentStart = elementStart + selectionStart;
    this.currentEnd = elementStart + selectionEnd;
  }

  removeSelected(mutableState: MutableState): void {
    mutableState.remove(this.currentStart, this.currentEnd);
  }
}

// this is a class which event-handlers use to mutate the current state
// its methods are whatever primitive methods are required by the event handlers which use it
// it's contructed from the previous RenderedState, then mutated, and then eventually returns the new RenderedState
class MutableState {
  private selection: { start: number, end: number };
  private buffer: string;
  // store the elements as word because until the mutation stops we don't know which will be the input element
  // e.g. what's currently current input element may be deleted and/or the input may be moved to a different word
  private words: string[];
  private context: Context;

  constructor(renderedState: RenderedState, context: Context) {
    // load the data from the previous state into non-readonly elements
    const { state, elements } = renderedState;
    this.selection = state.selection;
    this.buffer = state.buffer;
    this.words = elements.map(x => x.word); // use concat with no parameters to convert from ReadonlyArray to []
    this.context = context;

    // stash the input -- i.e. update the buffered data to reflect whatever is currently in the <input> element
    const { inputIndex } = getInputIndex(elements, context.assert);
    const { value, selectionStart, selectionEnd } = context.inputElement;
    this.replaceElement(inputIndex, value, { start: selectionStart, end: selectionEnd });
    log("MutableState", { selection: this.selection, buffer: this.buffer, words: this.words });
  }

  // called when the event handler has finished mutating this MutableState
  getState(): RenderedState {
    const state: State = { buffer: this.buffer, selection: this.selection };
    const { assert, inputElement, tagDictionary, validation } = this.context;
    const renderedState: RenderedState = renderState(state, assert, validation, inputElement, tagDictionary);
    logRenderedState("MutableState.getState returning", renderedState);
    // do a callback to the parent to say what the current tags are (excluding the empty <input> word if there is one)
    const tags: string[] = renderedState.elements.map(element => element.word).filter(word => !!word.length);
    const isValid = !renderedState.validationError.length;
    this.context.result({ tags, isValid });
    return renderedState;
  }

  replaceElement(index: number, newValue: string, selection?: { start: number, end: number }): void {
    this.invariant();

    const editingWord: string = this.words[index];
    // a special case is when the input element is empty and the last word -- then it's beyond the end of the buffer
    const nWords = this.words.length - ((this.words[this.words.length - 1] === "") ? 1 : 0);

    // if the new word matches the existing word then the replace will do nothing
    if (editingWord === newValue) {
      return;
    }
    const wordStart = getWordStart(this.words, index, this.context.assert);

    // possibly insert or delete whitespace before or after the word being added or deleted

    // if we delete the whole word and this isn't the last word then also delete the space after this word
    const deleteSpaceAfter = newValue === "" && index < nWords - 1;
    if (deleteSpaceAfter) {
      this.assertSpaceAt(wordStart + editingWord.length);
    }
    // if we delete the last word then delete the space before it
    const deleteSpaceBefore = newValue === "" && index === nWords - 1 && index !== 0;
    if (deleteSpaceBefore) {
      this.assertSpaceAt(wordStart - 1);
    }
    // if we add another word beyond a previous word (i.e. beyond the end of the buffer) then insert the space before it
    const addSpaceBefore = (wordStart === this.atBufferEnd()) && index;
    if (addSpaceBefore) {
      // assert this word was previously empty and is being changed to non-empty
      this.context.assert(!editingWord.length && !!newValue.length, "unexpected at end of buffer");
    }

    log("replaceElement", { deleteSpaceAfter, deleteSpaceBefore, addSpaceBefore });
    // calculate the deleteCount, and adjust deleteCount and/or wordStart and/or newValue, to insert or delete spaces

    const deleteCount: number = editingWord.length + (deleteSpaceAfter || deleteSpaceBefore ? 1 : 0);
    const spliceStart: number = (deleteSpaceBefore || addSpaceBefore) ? wordStart - 1 : wordStart;
    const spliceValue: string = (!addSpaceBefore) ? newValue : " " + newValue;

    // mutate the buffer
    this.buffer = stringSplice(this.buffer, spliceStart, deleteCount, spliceValue);
    // mutate the word in the elements array
    if (newValue.length) {
      this.words[index] = newValue;
    } else {
      this.words.splice(index, 1);
    }

    // adjust the selected range after mutating the text
    if (selection) {
      // called from constructor where new selection is taken from the <input> element
      const wordStart = getWordStart(this.words, index, this.context.assert);
      this.selection.start = selection.start + wordStart;
      this.selection.end = selection.end + wordStart;
    } else {
      // called from onDeleteTag where existing selection must be adjusted to account for the deleted element
      if (this.selection.start > wordStart) {
        this.selection.start -= deleteCount;
      }
      if (this.selection.end > wordStart) {
        this.selection.end -= deleteCount;
      }
    }
    this.invariant();
  }

  private invariant() {
    // we mutate the state but because we make several mutations this asserts that the state remains sane or predictable
    assertWords(this.words, this.buffer, this.context.assert);
  }
  private assertSpaceAt(index: number) {
    this.context.assert(this.buffer.substring(index, index + 1) === " ", "expected a space at this location");
  }

  remove(start: number, deleteCount: number): void {
    this.buffer = stringSplice(this.buffer, start, deleteCount, "");
  }

  // the start and end of the selection range are usually the same
  setSelectionBoth(where: number): void {
    this.selection.start = where;
    this.selection.end = where;
  }
  setSelectionStart(where: number): void {
    this.selection.start = where;
  }
  setSelectionEnd(where: number): void {
    this.selection.end = where;
  }
  // the location of the selection index beyond the end of the buffer (starting the empty, to-be-defined next tag)
  atBufferEnd(): number {
    return (this.buffer.length) ? this.buffer.length + 1 : 0;
  }

  selectEndOf(index: number) {
    const wordStart = getWordStart(this.words, index, this.context.assert);
    this.setSelectionBoth(wordStart + this.words[index].length);
  }
  focus() {
    this.context.inputElement.focus();
  }
};

// we want to display a maximum of 6 hints
const maxHints = 6;

// this is a class to lookup hints for existing tags which match the current input value
class TagDictionary {
  // the current implementation repeatedly iterates the whole dictionary
  // if that's slow (because the dictionary is large) in future we could partition the dictionary by letter
  private readonly tags: TagCount[];
  constructor(tags: TagCount[]) {
    this.tags = tags;
  }
  getHints(inputValue: string, elements: RenderedElement[]): TagCount[] {
    if (!inputValue.length) {
      return [];
    }
    // don't want what we already have i.e. what matches other tags
    const unwanted: string[] = elements.filter(x => x.type === "tag").map(x => x.word);
    // we'll select tags in the following priority:
    // 1. Tags where the inputValue matches the beginning of the tag
    // 2. If #1 returns too many tags, then prefer tags with a higher count because they're the more popular/more likely
    // 3. If #1 doesn't return enough tags, then find tags where the inputValue matches within the tag
    // 4. If #3 returns too many tags, then prefer tags with a higher count
    const findTags = (start: boolean, max: number): TagCount[] => {
      const found = (this.tags.filter(tag => start
        ? tag.key.startsWith(inputValue)
        : tag.key.substring(1).includes(inputValue))).filter(x => !unwanted.includes(x.key));
      // higher counts first, else alphabetic
      found.sort((x, y) => (x.count === y.count) ? x.key.localeCompare(y.key) : y.count - x.count);
      return found.slice(0, max);
    }
    const found = findTags(true, maxHints);
    return (found.length === maxHints) ? found : found.concat(findTags(false, maxHints - found.length));
  }
  exists(inputValue: string): boolean {
    return this.tags.some(tag => tag.key === inputValue);
  }
  toJSON(): string {
    // not worth logging all the elements
    return `${this.tags.length} elements`;
  }
}

/*
  The reducer
*/

interface ActionEditorClick { type: "EditorClick", context: Context };
interface ActionHintResult { type: "HintResult", context: Context, hint: string, inputIndex: number };
interface ActionDeleteTag { type: "DeleteTag", context: Context, index: number };
interface ActionTagClick { type: "TagClick", context: Context, index: number };
interface ActionKeyDown { type: "KeyDown", context: Context, key: string, shiftKey: boolean };
interface ActionChange { type: "Change", context: Context };

type Action = ActionEditorClick | ActionHintResult | ActionDeleteTag | ActionTagClick | ActionKeyDown | ActionChange;

function isEditorClick(action: Action): action is ActionEditorClick { return action.type === "EditorClick"; }
function isHintResult(action: Action): action is ActionHintResult { return action.type === "HintResult"; }
function isDeleteTag(action: Action): action is ActionDeleteTag { return action.type === "DeleteTag"; }
function isTagClick(action: Action): action is ActionTagClick { return action.type === "TagClick"; }
function isKeyDown(action: Action): action is ActionKeyDown { return action.type === "KeyDown"; }
function isChange(action: Action): action is ActionChange { return action.type === "Change"; }

function reducer(state: RenderedState, action: Action): RenderedState {

  log("reducer", action);
  const inputElement = action.context.inputElement;

  // this function returns a MutableState instance, which is based on the previous state plus the passed-in context
  // the passed-in context includes the new content of the <input> element
  function getMutableState(): MutableState {
    logRenderedState("getMutableState", state);
    return new MutableState(state, action.context);
  }
  // this function returns a InputState instance
  function getInputState(): InputState {
    return new InputState(state, inputElement, action.context.assert);
  }

  if (isChange(action)) {
    const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
    return mutableState.getState();
  }

  if (isEditorClick(action)) {
    // click on the <div> => set focus on the <input> within the <div>
    inputElement.focus();
    const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
    mutableState.setSelectionBoth(mutableState.atBufferEnd());
    return mutableState.getState();
  }

  if (isHintResult(action)) {
    // click on a hint => set focus on the <input>
    inputElement.focus();
    const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
    mutableState.replaceElement(action.inputIndex, action.hint);
    mutableState.setSelectionBoth(mutableState.atBufferEnd());
    return mutableState.getState();
  }

  if (isDeleteTag(action)) {
    const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
    mutableState.replaceElement(action.index, "");
    return mutableState.getState();
  }

  if (isTagClick(action)) {
    const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
    // want to position the cursor at the end of the selected word
    mutableState.selectEndOf(action.index);
    // clicking on the tag made the input lose the focus
    mutableState.focus();
    return mutableState.getState();
  }

  if (isKeyDown(action)) {
    const { key, shiftKey } = action;
    switch (key) {
      case "Home":
      case "ArrowUp": {
        // move selection to start of first tag
        const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
        mutableState.setSelectionBoth(0);
        return mutableState.getState();
      }

      case "End":
      case "ArrowDown": {
        // move selection to end of last tag
        const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
        mutableState.setSelectionBoth(mutableState.atBufferEnd());
        return mutableState.getState();
      }

      case "ArrowLeft": {
        const inputState: InputState = getInputState();
        // we're at the left of the input so traverse into the previous tag
        const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
        const wanted = inputState.nextLeft;
        if (shiftKey) {
          mutableState.setSelectionStart(wanted);
        } else {
          mutableState.setSelectionBoth(wanted);
        }
        return mutableState.getState();
      }
      case "ArrowRight": {
        const inputState: InputState = getInputState();
        // we're at the right of the input so traverse into the next tag
        const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
        const wanted = inputState.nextRight;
        if (shiftKey) {
          mutableState.setSelectionEnd(wanted);
        } else {
          mutableState.setSelectionBoth(wanted);
        }
        return mutableState.getState();
      }
      case "Backspace": {
        // same as ArrowLeft except also delete the space between the two tags
        const inputState: InputState = getInputState();
        const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
        if (shiftKey) {
          // also delete whatever is selected
          inputState.removeSelected(mutableState);
        }
        const wanted = inputState.nextLeft;
        mutableState.remove(wanted, 1);
        mutableState.setSelectionBoth(wanted);
        return mutableState.getState();
      }
      case "Delete": {
        // same as ArrowRight except also delete the space between the two tags
        const inputState: InputState = getInputState();
        const mutableState: MutableState = getMutableState();
        if (shiftKey) {
          // also delete whatever is selected
          inputState.removeSelected(mutableState);
        }
        const wanted = inputState.currentStart;
        mutableState.remove(wanted, 1);
        mutableState.setSelectionBoth(wanted);
        return mutableState.getState();
      }
      default:
        break;
    } // switch
  } // if isKeyDown

  logRenderedState("reducer returning old state", state);
  return state;
} // reducer

/*
  Various helper functions
*/

// Helper function analogous to Array.splice -- string has built-in slice but no splice
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
function stringSplice(text: string, start: number, deleteCount: number, insert: string): string {
  // up to but not including start
  const textStart = text.substring(0, start);
  const textEnd = text.substring(start + deleteCount);
  const after = textStart + insert + textEnd;
  log("stringSplice", { text, start, deleteCount, insert, after });
  return after;
}

function log(title: string, o: object, force?: boolean): void {
  if (!isLogging && !force) {
    return;
  }
  const json = JSON.stringify(o, null, 2);
  console.log(`${title} -- ${json}`);
}

function logRenderedState(title: string, renderedState: RenderedState): void {
  log(title, renderedState);
}

// this identifies the index of the one-and-only <input> element within the array of RenderedElement
function getInputIndex(elements: ReadonlyArray<RenderedElement>, assert: Assert)
  : { inputIndex: number, isFirst: boolean, isLast: boolean } {
  let inputIndex: number = 0;
  let counted = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    if (elements[i].type === "input") {
      ++counted;
      inputIndex = i;
    }
  }
  assert(counted === 1, "expected exactly one input element")
  return { inputIndex, isFirst: inputIndex === 0, isLast: inputIndex === elements.length - 1 };
}

// the getElementStart and assertElements functions have two versions
// i.e. they work with ReadonlyArray<RenderedElement> or ReadonlyArray<string>
// that's because the MutableState class works with ReadonlyArray<string> instead of ReadonlyArray<RenderedElement>
// because it doesn't yet know the type associated with each word

// Helper function to determine the offset into the buffer associated with a given RenderedElement
function getElementStart(elements: ReadonlyArray<RenderedElement>, index: number, assert: Assert): number {
  return getWordStart(elements.map(x => x.word), index, assert);
}
function getWordStart(words: ReadonlyArray<string>, index: number, assert: Assert): number {
  let wordStart = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
    const word = words[i];
    // +1 because there's a whitespace between i.e. after each word
    wordStart += word.length + 1;
    // assert all words are significant (and visible)
    // it's OK if the last word is empty i.e. if the <input> element is beyond the end of the buffer
    // that wouldn't trigger this assertion because we're only testing for all i < index
    assert(!!word.length, "getWordStart unexpected zero-length word");
  }
  return wordStart;
}

// assert that the state is as predicted
function assertElements(elements: ReadonlyArray<RenderedElement>, buffer: string, assert: Assert): void {
  assertWords(elements.map(x => x.word), buffer, assert);
  getInputIndex(elements, assert);
  elements.forEach((element, index) =>
    assert(!!element.word.length || (element.type === "input" && index === elements.length - 1),
      "unexpected zero-length word"));
}
function assertWords(words: ReadonlyArray<string>, buffer: string, assert: Assert): void {
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    const word = words[i];
    const wordStart = getWordStart(words, i, assert);
    const fragment = buffer.substring(wordStart, wordStart + word.length);
    assert(word === fragment, "assertElements",
      // don't bother to call JSON.stringify unless the assertion has actually failed
      () => { return { word, fragment, wordStart, length: word.length, buffer, words } });
  }
}

function getTextWidth(text: string) {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015393/49942
  const getContext = (): CanvasRenderingContext2D | undefined => {
    if (!(getTextWidth as any).canvas) {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      if (!context) {
        return undefined;
      }
      // matches the font famly and size defined in App.css
      context.font = '14px Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif';
      (getTextWidth as any).canvas = canvas;
      (getTextWidth as any).context = context;
    }
    return ((getTextWidth as any).context) as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  }
  const context = getContext();
  if (!context) {
    return 20;
  }
  return context.measureText(text).width;
}

// see [Simulating `:focus-within`](./EDITORTAGS.md#simulating-focus-within)
function handleFocus(e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLElement>, hasFocus: boolean) {
  function isElement(related: EventTarget | HTMLElement): related is HTMLElement {
    return (related as HTMLElement).tagName !== undefined;
  }
  // read it
  const target = e.target;
  const relatedTarget = e.relatedTarget;
  // relatedTarget is of type EventTarget -- upcast from that to HTMLElement
  const related: HTMLElement | undefined = (relatedTarget && isElement(relatedTarget)) ? relatedTarget : undefined;
  // get the tagName and className of the element
  const relatedName = (!relatedTarget) ? "!target" : (!related) ? "!element" : related.tagName;
  const relatedClass = (!related) ? "" : related.className;
  // log it
  const activeElement = document.activeElement;
  const targetName = target.tagName;
  const activeElementName = (activeElement) ? activeElement.tagName : "!activeElement";
  log("handleFocus", { hasFocus, targetName, activeElementName, relatedName, relatedClass });
  // calculate it
  hasFocus = hasFocus || (relatedClass === "hint");
  // write the result
  const div = document.getElementById("tag-both")!;
  if (hasFocus) {
    div.className = "focussed";
  } else {
    div.className = "";
  }
}

/*
  Functions which construct the RenderedState
*/

// this function calculates a new RenderedState and sets the InputElement content and selection, for a given State value
// it's called from initialState and from MutableState
function renderState(state: State, assert: Assert, validation: Validation,
  inputElement?: InputElement, tagDictionary?: TagDictionary)
  : RenderedState {
  const elements: RenderedElement[] = [];
  let editing: number | undefined = undefined;
  let inputValue: string = "";

  function setInput(text: string, start: number, end: number, inputElement: InputElement): void {
    log("setInput", { text, start, end });
    inputElement.setContent(text, start, end);
    inputValue = text;
    assert(start >= 0 && end <= text.length, `setInput invalid range: ${text} ${start} ${end}`)
  }

  function addElement(type: "tag" | "input", word: string): void {
    const isValid: boolean = !word.length || validation.canNewTag || (!!tagDictionary && tagDictionary.exists(word));
    elements.push({ type, word, isValid });
  }

  // split the buffer
  const words: string[] = state.buffer.split(" ").filter(word => word.length);
  const selection = state.selection;

  // this is where each word starts, an index into the buffer
  let wordStart = 0;
  // this accumulates previous words within the selection, when selection is a range which spans more than one word
  let accumulated: { wordStart: number, start: number, text: string } | undefined = undefined;

  for (let wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < words.length; ++wordIndex) {
    const word = words[wordIndex];
    // e.g. if a word's length is 1, then the positions within this word are 0 (start) and 1 (end)
    const wordEnd = wordStart + word.length;
    if ((selection.start > wordEnd) || (selection.end < wordStart)) {
      // selection is not in this word
      // - selection starts beyond the end of the word
      // - or selection ends before the start of the word
      addElement("tag", word);
    } else {
      if (!inputElement) {
        // the initialState function should set the selection at the end of the buffer
        // i.e. beyond any words (if there are any words)
        // or at the start of the buffer if there are no words,
        // so that it isn't necessary to set the selection inside the input element
        // given that the input element hasn't been created in the DOM yet
        assert(false, "invalid initial state")
        continue;
      }
      // selection includes some of this word
      // - selection starts on or before the end of the word
      // - or selection ends on or after the start of the word
      if (selection.start >= wordStart) {
        // selection starts in this word
        if (selection.end <= wordEnd) {
          // selection starts and ends in this word
          setInput(word, selection.start - wordStart, selection.end - wordStart, inputElement);
          editing = elements.length;
          addElement("input", word);
        } else {
          // starts in this word but ends in a future word
          assert(!accumulated, "shouldn't accumulate anything previously")
          accumulated = { wordStart, start: selection.start - wordStart, text: word };
        }
      } else {
        // selection started before this word
        if (!accumulated) {
          assert(false, "should have accumulated something previously");
          continue; // this is bad but better than referencing accumulated when it's undefined
        }
        // add to what's already accumulated, including inter-word whitespace
        accumulated.text += " " + word;
        if (selection.end <= wordEnd) {
          // selection ends in this word
          setInput(accumulated.text, accumulated.start, selection.end - accumulated.wordStart, inputElement);
          editing = elements.length;
          addElement("input", accumulated.text);
          accumulated = undefined;
        } else {
          // selection ends in a future word (and we already added this word to the accumulator)
        }
      }
    }
    wordStart += word.length + 1;
  }

  if (typeof editing === "undefined") {
    // we haven't pushed the <input> element yet, so push it now
    editing = elements.length;
    // if (initializing) then the `input` and `inputRef` values haven't yet been created because the state is created
    // before they are, via the call to initialState -- but when it is created it's initially empty so that's alright
    if (inputElement) {
      // the <input> element is already part of the DOM; reset it now
      setInput("", 0, 0, inputElement);
    }
    addElement("input", "");
  }

  assertElements(elements, state.buffer, assert);

  const hints: TagCount[] = !tagDictionary ? [] : tagDictionary.getHints(inputValue, elements);
  // if logging only log the keyword of each hint, otherwise logging the tags' summaries makes it long and hard to read
  (hints as any).toJSON = () => "[" + hints.map(hint => hint.key).join(",") + "]";

  function getValidationError(): string {
    const nWords: number = elements.filter(element => !!element.word.length).length;
    const invalid: string[] = elements.filter(element => !element.isValid).map(element => element.word);
    if (nWords < 1 && validation.minimum) {
      return "Please enter at least one tag;";
    }
    if (nWords > 5 && validation.maximum) {
      return "Please enter a maximum of five tags.";
    }
    if (!!invalid.length) {
      return (invalid.length === 1)
        ? `Tag '${invalid[0]}' does not match an existing topic.`
        : `Tags ${invalid.map(word => "'" + word + "'").join(" and ")} do not match existing topics.`
    }
    return "";
  }
  const validationError = getValidationError();

  const renderedState: RenderedState = { state, elements, inputValue, hints, validationError };
  return renderedState;
}

// this function calculates the initial state, calculated from props and used to initialize useState
function initialState(assert: Assert, inputTags: string[], validation: Validation): RenderedState {
  assert(!inputTags.some(found => found !== found.trim()), "input tags not trimmed", () => { return { inputTags }; });
  const buffer = inputTags.join(" ");
  const start = buffer.length + 1;
  const state: State = { buffer, selection: { start, end: start } };

  log("initialState starting", { inputTags })
  const renderedState: RenderedState = renderState(state, assert, validation);
  logRenderedState("initialState returning", renderedState)
  return renderedState;
}

/*

  EditorTags -- the functional component

*/

export const EditorTags: React.FunctionComponent<EditorTagsProps> = (props) => {

  const { inputTags, result, getAllTags } = props;
  const validation: Validation = props;

  /*
    React hooks
  */

  // this is an optional error message
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  function assert(assertion: boolean, message: string, extra?: () => object): void {
    if (!assertion) {
      if (extra) {
        const o: object = extra();
        const json = JSON.stringify(o, null, 2);
        message = `${message} -- ${json}`;
      }
      // write to errorMessage state means it's displayed by the `<ErrorMessage errorMessage={errorMessage} />` element
      setTimeout(() => {
        // do it after a timeout because otherwise if we do this during a render then React will complain with:
        //   "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."
        setErrorMessage(message);
      }, 0);
      console.error(message);
    }
  }

  // see ./EDITOR.md and the definition of the RenderedState interface for a description of this state
  // also https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/hooks/#usereducer says that type is infered from signature of reducer
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, inputTags,
    (inputTags) => initialState(assert, inputTags, validation));

  // this is a dictionary of existing tags
  const [tagDictionary, setTagDictionary] = React.useState<TagDictionary | undefined>(undefined);

  logRenderedState("--RENDERING--", state);

  // useEffect to fetch all the tags from the server exactly once
  // React's elint rules demand that getAllTags be specified in the deps array, but the value of getAllTags
  // (which we're being passed as a parameter) is utimately a function at module scope, so it won't vary
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // get tags from server
    getAllTags()
      .then((tags) => {
        // use them to contruct a dictionary
        const tagDictionary: TagDictionary = new TagDictionary(tags);
        // save the dictionary in state
        setTagDictionary(tagDictionary);
      })
      .catch((reason) => {
        // alarm the user
        setErrorMessage(`getAllTags() failed -- ${reason}`);
      });
  }, [getAllTags]);

  /*
    inputRef (data which is used by some of the event handlers)
  */

  const inputRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();

  /*
    Event handlers (which dispatch to the reducer)
  */

  function getContext(inputElement: HTMLInputElement): Context {
    return { inputElement: new InputElement(inputElement, assert), assert, result, tagDictionary, validation };
  }

  function handleEditorClick(e: React.MouseEvent) {
    const isDiv = (e.target as HTMLElement).tagName === "DIV";
    if (!isDiv) {
      // this wasn't a click on the <div> itself, presumably instead a click on something inside the div
      return;
    }
    dispatch({ type: "EditorClick", context: getContext(inputRef.current!) });
  }

  function handleDeleteTag(index: number, e: React.MouseEvent) {
    dispatch({ type: "DeleteTag", context: getContext(inputRef.current!), index });
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function handleTagClick(index: number, e: React.MouseEvent) {
    dispatch({ type: "TagClick", context: getContext(inputRef.current!), index });
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    dispatch({ type: "Change", context: getContext(e.target) });
  }

  function handleKeyDown(e: React.KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      // do nothing and prevent form submission
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
    // apparently dispatch calls the reducer asynchonously, i.e. after this event handler returns, which will be too
    // late to call e.preventDefault(), and so we need two-stage processing, i.e. some here and some inside the reducer:
    // - here we need to test whether the action will or should be handled within the reducer
    // - later in the reducer we need to actually perform the action
    function newinputState() {
      const inputElement: InputElement = new InputElement(e.target as HTMLInputElement, assert);
      return new InputState(state, inputElement, assert);
    }
    function isHandled(): boolean {
      switch (e.key) {
        case "Home":
        case "ArrowUp":
          // move selection to start of first tag
          return !getInputIndex(state.elements, assert).isFirst;
        case "End":
        case "ArrowDown":
          // move selection to end of last tag
          return !getInputIndex(state.elements, assert).isLast;
        case "ArrowLeft":
        case "Backspace": {
          const inputState: InputState = newinputState();
          return inputState.canMoveLeft;
        }
        case "ArrowRight":
        case "Delete": {
          const inputState: InputState = newinputState();
          return inputState.canMoveRight;
        }
        default:
          break;
      } // switch
      return false;
    }
    if (isHandled()) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const context: Context = getContext(e.target as HTMLInputElement);
      dispatch({ type: "KeyDown", context, key: e.key, shiftKey: e.shiftKey });
    }
  }

  function handleHintResult(outputTag: string) {
    const { inputIndex } = getInputIndex(state.elements, assert);
    dispatch({ type: "HintResult", context: getContext(inputRef.current!), hint: outputTag, inputIndex });
  }

  /*
    Tag is a FunctionComponent to render each tag
  */

  interface TagProps { text: string, index: number, isValid: boolean };
  const Tag: React.FunctionComponent<TagProps> = (props) => {
    const { text, index, isValid } = props;
    // https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const close = <a onClick={(e) => handleDeleteTag(index, e)} title="Remove tag"><Icon.Close height="12" /></a>;
    const className = isValid ? "tag" : "tag invalid";
    return <span className={className} onClick={(e) => handleTagClick(index, e)}>
      {text}
      {close}
    </span>
  }

  /*
    The return statement which yields the JSX.Element from this function component
  */

  function showValidationResult() {
    const showError = props.showValidationError && !!state.validationError.length;
    if (!showError) {
      return { className: "tag-editor", icon: undefined, validationError: undefined };
    }
    const className = "tag-editor invalid validated";
    const icon = <Icon.Error className="error" />;
    const validationErrorMessage = state.validationError;
    // use <a href={}> instead of <Link to={}> -- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6344
    const suffix = (validationErrorMessage[validationErrorMessage.length - 1] !== ";") ? undefined :
      (
        <React.Fragment>
          {"see a list of "}
          <a href={props.hrefAllTags} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">popular tags</a>{"."}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    const validationError = <p className="error">{validationErrorMessage} {suffix}</p>;
    return { validationError, icon, className };
  }
  const { validationError, icon, className } = showValidationResult();

  function getElement(element: RenderedElement, index: number): React.ReactElement {
    const isValid = !props.showValidationError || element.isValid;
    return (element.type === "tag")
      ? <Tag text={element.word} index={index} key={index} isValid={isValid} />
      : <input type="text" key="input" ref={inputRef} className={isValid ? undefined : "invalid"} width={10}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} onChange={handleChange}
        onFocus={e => handleFocus(e, true)} onBlur={e => handleFocus(e, false)} />
  }

  return (
    <div id="tag-both" >
      <div className={className} onClickCapture={handleEditorClick}>
        {state.elements.map(getElement)}
        {icon}
      </div>
      <ShowHints hints={state.hints} inputValue={state.inputValue} result={handleHintResult} />
      <ErrorMessage errorMessage={errorMessage} />
      {validationError}
    </div>
  );
}

/*

  ShowHints

*/

interface ShowHintsProps {
  // hints (from dictionary)
  hints: TagCount[],
  // the current value of the tag in the editor
  inputValue: string,
  // callback of tag selected from list of hints if user clicks on it
  result: (outputTag: string) => void
}
const ShowHints: React.FunctionComponent<ShowHintsProps> = (props) => {
  const { hints, inputValue, result } = props;
  if (!inputValue.length) {
    return <div className="tag-hints hidden"></div>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="tag-hints">
      {!hints.length ? "No results found." : hints.map(hint =>
        <ShowHint hint={hint} inputValue={inputValue} result={result} key={hint.key} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

interface ShowHintProps {
  // hints (from dictionary)
  hint: TagCount,
  // the current value of the tag in the editor
  inputValue: string,
  // callback of tag selected from list of hints if user clicks on it
  result: (outputTag: string) => void
}
const ShowHint: React.FunctionComponent<ShowHintProps> = (props) => {
  const { hint, inputValue, result } = props;

  function getTag(key: string) {
    const index = key.indexOf(inputValue);
    return (
      <span className="tag">
        {(index === -1) ? key :
          <React.Fragment>
            {key.substring(0, index)}
            <span className="match">{inputValue}</span>
            {key.substring(index + inputValue.length)}
          </React.Fragment>}
      </span>
    );
  }
  // the key with the matched letters highlighted
  const tag = getTag(hint.key);
  // count the number of times this tag is used elsewhere, if any
  const count = (hint.count) ? <span className="multiplier">×&nbsp;{hint.count}</span> : undefined;
  // the summary, if any
  const summary = (hint.summary) ? <p>{hint.summary}</p> : undefined;
  // a link to more info i.e. the page which defines this tag
  function getMore(key: string) {
    const icon = <Icon.Info width="16" height="16" />;
    // we use <a> here instead of <Link> because this link will open a whole new tab, i.e. another instance of this SPA
    // in future I think it would be better to reimplement this as a split screen (two-column) view
    const anchor = <a href={`/tags/${key}/info`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{icon}</a>;
    return <p className="more-info">{anchor}</p>;
  }
  const more = getMore(hint.key);
  return (
    <div className="hint" tabIndex={0} key={hint.key}
      onClick={e => result(hint.key)}
      onKeyDown={e => { if (e.key === "Enter") result(hint.key); e.preventDefault() }}
      onFocus={e => handleFocus(e, true)} onBlur={e => handleFocus(e, false)} >
      {tag}
      {count}
      {summary}
      {more}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### EDITORTAGS.md

This is a README for the source file above.

You don't have to read this. I wrote it because there a couple of tricky things in the implementation -- design decisions, e.g. to do with "focus-within" -- which I didn't want to document as comments in the source code.

> ## `EditorTags`
>
> The `EditorTags` component lets you edit and select the tags associated with a topic.
>
> - Appearance and behaviour
> - Implementation state data
> - Sequence of definitions
>
>   - Problem constraints
>   - Solution as implemented
> - Controlling the `<input>` element
> - Simulating `:focus-within`
>
> ### Appearance and behaviour
>
> It looks like a simple `<input type="text">` control, which contains multiple words -- one word per tag --
>   however all words except the currently-selected word have some visible style applied to them.
>
> It's implemented as a `<div>` like this:
>
> ```
>   function getElement(element: RenderedElement, index: number): React.ReactElement {
>     const isValid = !props.showValidationError || element.isValid;
>     return (element.type === "tag")
>       ? <Tag text={element.word} index={index} key={index} isValid={isValid} />
>       : <input type="text" key="input" ref={inputRef} className={isValid ? undefined : "invalid"} width={10}
>         onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} onChange={handleChange}
>         onFocus={e => handleFocus(e, true)} onBlur={e => handleFocus(e, false)} />
>   }
>
>   return (
>     <div id="tag-both" >
>       <div className={className} onClickCapture={handleEditorClick}>
>         {state.elements.map(getElement)}
>         {icon}
>       </div>
>       <ShowHints hints={state.hints} inputValue={state.inputValue} result={handleHintResult} />
>       <ErrorMessage errorMessage={errorMessage} />
>       {validationError}
>     </div>
>   );
> ```
>
> The `<div>` -- and the `state.elements` array shown above -- contains:
>
> - Exactly one `<input>` element, in which you edit the currently-selected word
> - One or more React components of my type `<Tag>`, which style the other words which you're not currently editing
>
> The `<input>` element may be:
>
> - Alone in the `<div>`
> - The first or the last element in the `<div>`, either before or after all `<Tag>` elements
> - In the middle of the `<div>`, with `<Tag>` elements to its left and right
>
> When you use the cursor keys (including <kbd>ArrowLeft</kbd> and <kbd>ArrowRight</kbd>) to scroll beyond the edge of
>   the `<input>` control, then this component detects that and changes its selection of which tag is currently editable.
>
> ### Implementation state data
>
> There's quite a bit of state (i.e. member data) associated with this component:
>
> - A `state.buffer` string whose value equals the current string or array of words (i.e. tags) being edited
> - A `state.selection` index or range, that identifies which word is currently being edited --
>     this is a `start` and `end` range, because you can select a range of text,
>     e.g. by pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you use the cursor keys
> - The `elements` array, which is calculated from the buffer and the selection range, and which identifies which word is
>     associated with the `<input>` element and which other words are associated with the `<Tag>` elements.
> - The `inputValue` which identifies the current value of the `<input>` element
> - A `hints` array which lists the possible tags which might be a match for the input value
> - A `validationError` message if the current tags are invalid and deserve an error message
>
> ```
> // this is like the input data from which the RenderedState is calculated
> // these and other state elements are readonly so that event handlers must mutate MutableState instead
> interface State {
>   // the selection range within the buffer
>   // this may even span multiple words, in which case all the selected words are in the <input> element
>   readonly selection: { readonly start: number, readonly end: number },
>   // the words (i.e. the tags when this is split on whitespace)
>   readonly buffer: string
> };
>
> // this interface identifies the array of <input> and <Tag> elements to be rendered, and the word associated with each
> interface RenderedElement {
>   // the string value of this word
>   readonly word: string;
>   // whether this word is rendered by a Tag element or by the one input element
>   readonly type: "tag" | "input";
>   // whether this word matches an existing tag in the dictionary
>   readonly isValid: boolean;
> };
>
> // this interface combines the two states, and is what's stored using useReducer
> interface RenderedState {
>   // the buffer which contains the tag-words, and the selection within the buffer
>   readonly state: State;
>   // how that's rendered i.e. the <input> element plus <Tag> elements
>   readonly elements: ReadonlyArray<RenderedElement>;
>   // the current ("semi-controlled") value of the <input> element
>   readonly inputValue: string;
>   // the hints associated with the inputValue, taken from the TagDictionary
>   hints: TagCount[];
>   // the validation error message (zero length if there isn't one)
>   validationError: string;
> }
> ```
>
> Because there's a lot of data, and the data elements are inter-related,
>   I implement it with `useReducer` instead of `useState`.
>
> ### Sequence of definitions
>
> The sequence in which things are defined in the source file is significant --
>   and it's fragile, i.e. if you don't do it right then there's a compiler error about using something before it's defined,
>   or a run-time error about using something with an undefined value.
>
> I use the following strategy:
>
> - Because the `initialState` and therefore the `renderState` functions are called when the `state` is initialized and
>     before `inputRef.current` exists, this function and anything called from this function cannot reference the state data.
> - To ensure they don't reference the state data, they're defined in the `EditorTabs.tsx` module (for convenience),
>     but defined outside the `EditorTags` function component inside which the state data are defined, so that the compiler
>     would error if they were referenced from those functions.
>
> So the following are defined outside the function component:
>
> - The `initialState` and `renderState` functions
> - Any TypeScript class definitions which these functions use
> - Any other TypeScript type definitions which these functions or classes use -- so, for simplicity, every TypeScript
>     type definition.
> - Any small helper/utility functions which these functions use -- and so, for simplicity, all helper/utility functions
> - Because a reducer should be stateless or pure, it too is defined outside the function component
> - And therefore also the TypeScript type definitions of the action types, and the corresponding user-defined type guards
>
> So the following remain inside the function component:
>
> - All state data
> - All event handlers (which delegate to the reducer, and which may reference `inputRef.current`)
> - The `assert` function depends on the `setErrorMessage` function, which is state -- so the `assert` function too is
>     defined inside the function component, and is passed as a parameter to any function which needs it.
>
> Data that's stored inside the function component, and which isn't stored as state,
>   is passed to the reducer in the "action".
>
> ```js
> interface ActionEditorClick { type: "EditorClick", context: Context };
> interface ActionHintResult { type: "HintResult", context: Context, hint: string, inputIndex: number };
> interface ActionDeleteTag { type: "DeleteTag", context: Context, index: number };
> interface ActionTagClick { type: "TagClick", context: Context, index: number };
> interface ActionKeyDown { type: "KeyDown", context: Context, key: string, shiftKey: boolean };
> interface ActionChange { type: "Change", context: Context };
> ```
>
> All the `Action` types include an `InputElement` (which is created by the event handler which generates the action),
>   because the `MutableState` class (called from the reducer) requires an `InputElement`, in order to update the `State`
>   (including the `buffer` and the `selection`) to match the contents of the `<input>` element.
>
> In fact there's other data too, which the reducer needs and is passed in the action:
>
> ```js
> // this is extra data which event handlers pass (as part of the action) from the function component to the reducer
> interface Context {
>   inputElement: InputElement;
>   assert: Assert;
>   result: ParentCallback;
>   tagDictionary?: TagDictionary;
>   validation: Validation;
> };
> ```
>
> ### Controlling the `<input>` element
>
> The `<input>` element is a semi-controlled component (see e.g.
>   "[What are Controlled Components in React?](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-controlled-components/)").
>
> There's an `inputRef` as well to access to the underlying HTML element, which is used to set the focus, and
>   to get and set the selection range within the element, but not to get the value of the element --
>   the value of the element is got via its `onChange` handler (and the `value` property of the event's `target`).
>
> Note that React's `onChange` event handler has redefined (non-standard) semantics -- i.e. it's fired after every change,
>   and not only when it loses focus.
>
> I say that it's "semi" controlled, because although its `onChange` handler writes its value to state ...
>
> ```js
> <input type="text" ref={inputRef} onChange={handleChange} ...
> ```
>
> ... it does **not** have a corresponding `value` property which might read its value from state ...
>
> ```js
> <input type="text" ref={inputRef} onChange={handleChange} value={state.inputValue} ...
> ```
>
> The reason why not is because if the value property is used to write a string into a previously-empty
>   input element, then the selection range within the control is automatically pushed to the end of the new string.
>
> This interferes with the desired behaviour of the <kbd>ArrowRight</kbd> key, where we want to copy
>   the next (to the right) tag into the input control, and set the selection range to the **beginning** of the control.
>
> So, instead, the `setInput` function writes into the `value` property of the underlying `HTMLInputElement`.
>
> - I worried that doing this might trigger another `onChange` event, but it doesn't seem to.
> - An alternative might be to use `useEffect` to alter the selection of the input (to match the selection specified in
>     the state), after it's rendered.
>     That seems like even more of a kluge, though -- making it "semi-controlled" instead, i.e. writing to the DOM element,
>     seems neater.
>
> The `inputValue` element also still exists as an alement of the `RenderedState` data,
>   but it's write-only -- i.e. it's up-to-date (and a opy of what was written into the DOM element).
>
> ### Simulating `:focus-within`
>
> There are a couple of effects in `EditorTags.css` for example ...
>
> ```css
> .tag-hints {
>   visibility: hidden;
> }
>
> .tag-both:focus-within .tag-hints {
>   visibility: visible;
> }
> ```
>
> ... where is would be convenient to use `:focus-within`. However that's not supported by some browsers (e.g. Edge).
>   Although the "Create React App" setup include `postcss` modules, they're not configurable --
>   "[You cannot customize postcss rules](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5749#issuecomment-436852753)"
>   -- and the default configuration doesn't enable support for `postcss-focus-within`.
>
> To avoid the complexity or fragility of trying to bypass the CRA default configuration,
>   instead I use `onfocus` and `onBlur` handlers to simulate `:focus-within`
>   (by adding or removing `focussed` to the `class` value).
>
> There's also complexity in deciding whether something has lost focus.
>
> - The problem is that, using React's synthetic events, `onBlur` fires before `onFocus` --
>     so focus seems lost when focus moves from `.tag-editor input` to one of the `.hint` elements.
> - The right the right way to support this functionality would be to use the `focusin` event as described in
>     [Focus Event Order](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20140925/#events-focusevent-event-order),
>     however React's synthetic events don't support `focusin` -- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6410
>
> Solutions like ...
>
> - [Dealing with focus and blur in a composite widget in
>     React](https://medium.com/@jessebeach/dealing-with-focus-and-blur-in-a-composite-widget-in-react-90d3c3b49a9b)
> - The [`react-focus-within`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-focus-within) package
>
> ... solve this using a timer in some way --
>   which is probably good, only I'm not certain of the sequence in which events are emitted.
>
> So instead I use a solution (see the `handleFocus` function) which depends on the `relatedTarget` of the event:
>
> - That works on my machine (Windows 10), at least, using Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.
> - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3751 warns that apparently this won't work with IE 9 through IE 11,
>     though comments there say that document.activeElement might help make it work on IE
>
> Otherwise, if support for IE (not just Edge) is needed, one of the other solutions listed earlier above might be better.

Comment: (Not an expert here) The main behavioral difference I could see at a glance would be that in the SE network the tag recommendations "hover" over/hide the button, while your implementation push it towards the bottom of the page. I have to admit that I have not read your whole post, so I might have missed it if you describe this behavior as intentional there.

Comment: You're right, that is one (unintentional) difference -- presumably a difference in the CSS, e.g. the CSS could `position` the hint-recommendations `div`, to take it out of the normal flow sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: My usage of ReactJS is very limited so there are likely things a developer more experienced with it would point out.*

> Are there too many comments in the code?

It doesn't look like *too many* comments. Anything that helps readers (including your future self) is a good thing. It isn't like [this "not funny" code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/10167/120114) that has excessive, non-constructive comments. It is believed that some object-oriented code can be self-documenting but it would still be necessary to explain what methods/functions do, as well as describe any parameters and return values.

> It's pretty long: so would it be better split into more than one source file and if so how would that help and how/where should it be split?

My natural inclination is to suggest that the code be split so each class/interface is in a separate file. I see that a lot of the code is comprised of functions... some of those could possibly be put into one or more files for helper functions.

> And/or any other review comment you think appropriate.

Most of the methods don't appear to be overly lengthy. I see `MutableState:: replaceElement()` looks like an outlier so that would be a candidate for being broken up into separate smaller methods. And `reducer()` is also a bit lengthy, though it may be challenging to break that up. I do see a lot of repeated lines in that function - e.g. calling `getMutableState()` to create a `MutableState` object and then ultimately returning the return value from calling `getState()` on that object.

---

This code makes good use of `const` for any variable that doesn't get re-assigned and `let` for variable that may be re-assigned, as well as object destructuring.

---

Correct me if I am wrong, but `MutableState::setSelectionBoth()` should be able to be simplified from:

> ```
> setSelectionBoth(where: number): void {
>   this.selection.start = where;
>   this.selection.end = where;
> }
> ```

to:

```
setSelectionBoth(where: number): void {
  this.selection.end = this.selection.start = where;
}
```

---

There are some `for` loops, like the one in `renderState()` that could be simplified with a [`for...of`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#forof-statements) loop instead -

e.g.

> ```
> for (let wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < words.length; ++wordIndex) {
>   const word = words[wordIndex];
> ```

This could be simplified to:

```
for (const word of words) {
```

That way you don't have to increment `wordIndex` manually or use it to access `word` from `words` with the bracket syntax.

Comment: `getWordStart` compares `i` to `index` (in the `for` expression itself) because it only wants the first few words. I could have done `for (const word of words.slice(0, index)) {` or something like that instead -- it's my old (arguably obsolete) habits have me prefer to use an index, than to instantiate a new array using `slice`.

Comment: I realise that one-function-per-file was like the default in C, and one-class-per-file in C++, but ... there are about 50 function and type definitions in this module, I'm not convinced it would be easier to read or understand or anything as 50 different source files -- are you? Admittedly I use the split-screen (i.e. side-by-side) feature of the text editor (i.e. VS Code) sometimes, so see two places at once within the same file (e.g. the new bit I'm coding and the existing bit I'm about to call), and I felt a need for that map or index of identifiers/definitions, nears the top, in a comment.

Comment: It's currently physically one module (i.e. one source file) with a narrow public interface (i.e. very little is exported), almost everything is "private" to the module -- an implementation detail, not exported.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance about the comments, at least. I had someone (not very experienced) complain that I comment too much. I know (e.g. from the "Socratic" discussion in _Code Complete_) that the topic (i.e. to comment or not) is debatable -- also that it can look inconsistent when there's a code-base with multiple authors, some with a lot of comments and some with none.

Comment: I guess that 50 source files is too much of the opposite extreme. I wondered if there's an especially natural or idiomatic way (like a "fault line" along which) to split such code, and whether there's a compelling pragmatic consideration.

Comment: Ah I was incorrect about that loop in `getWordStart()` - but there are others - e.g. the one in `renderState()`; Yeah ~50 files would feel too many... I bet you could perhaps make a couple - e.g. one for `InputElement`, `InputState`and one for `MutableState`.... taking those three classes out would reduce the one file size dramatically

Answer (score 3):

Any code should be readable as we read code 90% time in our overall dealing of code, this code doesn't seem very readable, this can be reviewed better after making some basic changes and after that, it can be review to find real problems or can be refactored.

1. Proper naming like `TagCount` is not actually a count similarly `Validation` is not just validation it is validations applicable on tag
2. Once your naming is proper no need this much of comments, your code should be self explainable, unnecessary comments are noise
3. Functions should be small and composite
4. Reducer is not a pure function
5. lot of functions created inside other functions these can be put out as an independent method for readability

Comment: Why do you say "reducer is not a pure function" -- what does it depend on apart from its input values?

Comment: Mutable state and input state are maintaining things on instance, if function is pure then these are just confusing, as I said this can be better reviewed if it is readable

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand or don't agree with your comments re. naming. For example `TagCount` *is* a count -- it contains a `count` member which is the number of times that tag has been used (which affects how the hint is displayed e.g. with a `x 2` next to it, also the more-frequently-used tags with a higher count are prefered). I agree in principle that names are important but I already tried to name things so I don't see how to improve them so "give things proper names" isn't actionable advice.

Comment: Perhaps I'd have to ask you what you think the (better) names should be, but you say you don't want to review until after things are renamed, so ...

Comment: I also think it's helpful to have comments as well as code -- that the right kind of comment can make it quicker+easier to understand what's supposed to be happening, instead of the reader having to decypher the code and only being able to see what *is* happening and not also what's *intended*. People might be happier reading code than English, though, and I agree that comments are no substitute for "self-documenting" code e.g. with well-named identifiers.

Comment: Thank you for the comment about `InputState`, that was a good observation. I posted a new question on Statck Overflow about that -- [Must a React reducer be a pure function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57142137/49942)